# XPATH for checking value of an xml element based on another element's value

Tags: xml, xpath

My XML looks like the below one. I want to check the value of 'number' when //book//genre/text()='classic' , i want to return both 1000 and 1003. Can anybody help please?

```
<list>
<book>
    <author>
        <name>John</name>
        <number>1000</number>
    </author>
    <otherDetails>
        <genre>classic</genre>
        <price>$50</price>
    </otherDetails>
    <title>Dusk</title>
    <isbn>dsdaassda</isbn>
</book>
<book>
    <author>
        <name>MARK</name>
        <number>1001</number>
    </author>
    <otherDetails>
        <genre>comedy</genre>
        <price>$140</price>
    </otherDetails>
    <title>Midnight</title>
    <isbn>dsdaassda</isbn>
</book>
<book>
    <author>
        <name>Pete</name>
        <number>1003</number>
    </author>
    <otherDetails>
        <genre>classic</genre>
        <price>$140</price>
    </otherDetails>
    <title>Morning</title>
    <isbn>EFGH</isbn>
</book>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/list/book[otherDetails/genre='classic']/author/number`

Comment: @vpk it does. Be aware that node and attribute names and values are case-sensitive